# Can $ \boldsymbol{u}' - \boldsymbol{A}(t) \boldsymbol{u} = \boldsymbol{f}(t)$ be solved using an matrix exponential integrating factor?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Can

$$ \boldsymbol{u}' - \boldsymbol{A}(t) \boldsymbol{u} = \boldsymbol{f}(t)$$

be solved using an integration factor method analogous to that used in the non-system case? (i.e. $u'-a(t)u=f(t)$). Giving the following solution:

$$ \boldsymbol{u} = e^{-\int^t A(k)dk}\left (\int^t e^{\int^s A(k)dk}\boldsymbol{f}(s) ds + \boldsymbol{c}\right )$$

where the matrix exponential defined in the usual way. If you rearrange the solution and differentiate you find
$$
\frac
{\text{d}e^{-\int^t A(k)dk}}
{\text{d}t}
\boldsymbol{u}
+
e^{-\int^t A(k)dk}
\boldsymbol{u}'
=
e^{-\int^t A(k)dk}
\boldsymbol{f}
$$

If this is indeed the solution, it would then imply that
$$
\frac
{\text{d}e^{-\int^t A(k)dk}}
{\text{d}t}
= 
- e^{-\int^t A(k)dk} \boldsymbol{A}
$$

However this doesn't seem to be the case from Eq. 2.1 of http://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1705306
referenced on the Wiki page for [matrix exponentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

EDIT: Disproved on [page 6 here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/ExpMatrix.pdf).

Comment: If your $A$ is time-dependent, then there is no simple closed formula. If $A$ is constant instead then there is a closed form solution.

Comment: @MrYouMath: Yes, I believe you are correct.

Comment: Related to [What really is a path-ordered exponential?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1264922/115115), [How to compute time ordered Exponential?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2143963/115115), [Peano-Baker series and ordered exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2248022/115115)